# QFileDialog created without file extension in linux

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I am creating a file in both windows and linux using QFileDialog

```
fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Create project"), applicationPath,tr("Files (*.MSC)"));
```

In windows the file is created as path/to/file.MSC
but in linux file is created as path/to/file

why .MSC is not appending in Linux, whether we need to use other function for this

Comment: The native file-dialogs don't work the same way on all platforms.

Comment: @Sijith please share the rest of your code, QFileDialog only asks user for the file name. It won't save your data, because it doesn't even know what data to save.

Comment: I printed file name in both platform after giving the name in QFile Dialog, windows automatically appended.MSC in end but linux didnt do it. Remaining code I am working with the filename, Nothing to do with dialog after this

Comment: As stated by ekhumoro, this is the way these dialogs behave on each platform. There is no changing that. You could try to use the non-native dialogs by passing the `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` option.

Answer (score 0):

The following example works fine on Linux. You get the file `myfile.MSC` with the text "test" written on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString applicationPath = QDir::currentPath() + "/myfile.MSC";

    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(0,
                                                    QApplication::tr("Create project"),
                                                    applicationPath,
                                                    QApplication::tr("Files (*.MSC)"));

    if (fileName.isEmpty())
        return -1;
    else {
        QFile file(fileName);
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
            std::cout << "error\n";
            return -1;
        }

        QDataStream out(&file);
        out << "test";
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```